# ¿BUG? can not create file with '=' via command line ECHO and COPY CON

Tags: command-line, filenames, ms-dos, special-characters, documentation

WHERE is the documentation that explains the apparently anomalous behaviour of the *equal sign* below?

STEPS TO REPRODUCE (at a command prompt):

example with ECHO:

```
H:\BUGS>echo abc > a-b.txt
H:\BUGS>echo cde > c=d.txt
H:\BUGS>dir
2016-03-13  19:54  6 a-b.txt
2016-03-13  19:54 12 c
H:\BUGS>type a-b.txt
abc
H:\BUGS>type c
cde =d.txt
```

**Notes:**
file **c**:

```
636465203D642E7478740D0A    
c d e   = d . t x t
```

file **a-b.txt**:

```
616263200D0A    
a b c
```

HOWEVER (here the '=' becomes part of the valid file names if i use quotes):

```
H:\BUGS>ren a-b.txt a=b.txt
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

H:\BUGS>ren a-b.txt "a=b.txt"
H:\BUGS>ren c       "c=d.txt"
H:\BUGS>dir
2016-03-13  19:54   6 a=b.txt
2016-03-13  19:54  12 c=d.txt
```

an *equal sign* is a valid file name character.

FWIW, it appears that a '=' not in quotes has a bizarre special meaning on a DOS command line.

OTOH, the '=' is a valid file name character.

"*[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)*"

using Windows 8.1

edit:

```
H:\BUGS>echo def > "d=e.txt"
H:\BUGS>dir
2016-03-13  20:36 6 d=e.txt
H:\BUGS>type "d=e.txt"
def
```

the syntax above works.

end edit.

edit #2:

[Michael Frank](https://superuser.com/users/128359/michael-frank) helped me find more information.

His information enabled me to locate an interesting SO article "*[cmd- comma to separate parameters Compared to space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156438/cmd-comma-to-separate-parameters-compared-to-space)*"

```
H:\BUGS>type Frank.cmd
@echo %1/%2/%3

H:\BUGS>Frank 1 2 3
1/2/3

H:\BUGS>Frank 1=2=3
1/2/3

H:\BUGS>Frank 1;2;3
1/2/3

H:\BUGS>Frank 1,2,3
1/2/3

H:\BUGS>Frank 1/2/3
1/2/3//
```

in the above, various characters are used as delimiters.

when `/` was used as a delimiter above, an extra `/` is emitted; that would be a bug imho.

at "*[cmd- comma to separate parameters Compared to space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156438/cmd-comma-to-separate-parameters-compared-to-space)*", [Tim Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32133/tim-robinson) wrote "*on Windows, programs are responsible for parsing their own command lines. The shell parses redirects and pipes, **then passes the rest of the command line to the program in one string***"

BOTTOM LINE:  it appears that where a delimiter is needed, `=` acts as a delimiter; in some cases `=` causes a *syntax* error, in other cases `=` is simply an *equal sign*.

end edit #2.

Comment: searching for an explanation via Google was unsuccessful; while the workaround resolves the problem, for me finding this in the documentation is important; any help is appreciated.

Comment: Escape the `=` with a `^`. For example: `echo cde>c^=d.txt`.

Comment: @MichaelFrank yes, that also works; thank you; however, what i really wish to know is why that `=` behaves like this; `=` is not one of the special characters listed here "*[Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions)*" ~~ `<` (less than); `>` (greater than); `:` (colon); `"` (double quote); `/` (forward slash); `\` (backslash); `|` (vertical bar or pipe); `?` (question mark); `*`(asterisk)

Comment: See my answer below, but basically it is a delimiter character, used to separate commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=` character is a delimiter, functionally it seems to be the same as a space . As you can see in the example below:

```
c:\NotBackedUp>echo abc>d efg.txt

c:\NotBackedUp>type d
abc efg.txt
```

Likewise, `=` will do the same thing:

```
c:\NotBackedUp>echo abc>d=efg.txt

c:\NotBackedUp>type d
abc=efg.txt
```

Let's take a look at your first command: `echo cde > c=d.txt`

Starting off, you invoke the `echo` command, then pass it a value `cde` to insert into file `c`. Because `=` is a delimiter and you haven't told `echo` where to send the next string `d.txt`, it defaults to the previous file: `c`.

You can get around this by either quoting your output name:

```
c:\NotBackedUp>echo abc>"d=e.txt"
```

or by escaping the delimiter with `^`:

```
c:\NotBackedUp>echo abc>d^=e.txt
```

Both of these will create a file `d=e.txt` with contents `abc`.

[Further information about Delimiters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: thank you for the link to the Simon Sheppard site [ss64.com](ss64.com) ... see my edit #2.  You are correct in that *sometimes* `=` acts like a delimiter.  For me, it is surprising that Microsoft has not documented this; my preference would have been to have found documentation from Microsoft; regardless, because Simon Sheppard's website directed me to a better understanding, i'm marking your answer as the answer.